# Not hardcoded path doesn't work on picasso android studio

Tags: android, picasso

I am having trouble using picasso on android studio.

I am using picasso for loading the image from my database

Here's my code for loading my image

```
String resultImageUrl = removeCharAt(pImage,31);
Picasso.get().load(resultImageUrl).into(image_profile);
```

The problem with the code above is that it doesn't work but if hardcode the path

```
Picasso.get().load("http://192.168/254/123/myapp/admin/images/12378123asdjh.jpg").into(image_profile);
```

That code loads the image. What should I do?

I already tried doing it like this

```
String newUrl = "\"http://" + resultImageUrl + "\"";
Picasso.get().load(newUrl).into(image_profile);
```

But no luck

Comment: Replace http with https.

Comment: `http` does work too actually if it is hardcoded path so there's no problem either `http` or `https`

Comment: So, what does `resultImageUrl` resolve to?

Comment: the result image is this `192.168/254/123/myapp/admin/images/12378123asdjh.jpg` @PPartisan

Comment: So, you can do `String.format("http://%s", resultImageUrl)`. Or, you could also use a `Uri.Builder` for this, but `String#format` should be fine.

Comment: @PPartisan it did work . Thank you . Could you write down that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string:

```
resultImageUrl = "192.168/254/123/myapp/admin/images/12378123asdjh.jpg";
```

that you want to prefix with `http://`, then you can use `String#format`:

```
String.format("http://%s", resultImageUrl);
```

**Edit:** An interesting alternative could also be to use a `Uri.Builder`, although it's better when you have each individual path segment:

```
final String url = new Uri.Builder()
  .scheme("http")
  .path(resultImageUrl)
  .build().toString();
```